# Side Menu in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages with Web API

Tags: mysql, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Can anyone give me an example for doing a side menu in ASP.net Core?
I have an example below, but I don't know how to use it.

```
[
  {
    "MenuName": "Hirer HP Transactions",
    "MenuList": [
      {
        "MenuName": "HP Application Master",
        "MenuList": []
      },
      {
        "MenuName": "HP Hirer Master",
        "MenuList": []
      },
      {
        "MenuName": "HP Collection",
        "MenuList": []
      },
      {
        "MenuName": "Post Dated Cheque",
        "MenuList": []
      },
      {
        "MenuName": "Operation Reports",
        "MenuList": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MenuName": "Vehicle Trading Transactions",
    "MenuList": [
      {
        "MenuName": "Purchase Agreement",
        "MenuList": [
          {
            "MenuName": "Open Vehicle Module",
            "MenuList": []
          },
          {
            "MenuName": "Open / Unsold Vehicles",
            "MenuList": []
          },
          {
            "MenuName": "Import Vehicle Delivery Monitoring",
            "MenuList": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "MenuName": "Sales Order",
        "MenuList": []
      },
      {
        "MenuName": "Sales Agreement",
        "MenuList": []
      },
      {
        "MenuName": "Stock Master",
        "MenuList": []
      },
      {
        "MenuName": "Operation Reports",
        "MenuList": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer :

1. query your db and get the menus data
2. render the menus into html .

Since you have the menus data already, I'll show you how to render it with about 40 lines of JavaScript codes :

Firstly , create a `Sidebar.lib.js` that helps to render your menus to html :

```
function SideBar(menus=[],onclick){
    this.menus=menus;
    this.onclick= onclick;
}

SideBar.prototype.render = function(){
    return `<ul class="nav bd-sidenav">${this.menus.map(m=> this._renderListItem(m)).join("")}</ul>`;
}

SideBar.prototype.attach=function(elementContainer = new HTMLElement()){
    var innerHtml = this.render();
    elementContainer.innerHTML= innerHtml;
    elementContainer.onclick = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if(e.srcElement.tagName.toLowerCase()=="a"){
            if(this.onclick != null) this.onclick(e.target);
        }
        return false;
    };
}

SideBar.prototype._renderListItem = function(li){
    if(Array.isArray(li.MenuList) && li.MenuList.length >0 ){
        return `<li>
            <a href="#${li.MenuName}">${li.MenuName}</a>
            <ul> ${li.MenuList.map(item=> this._renderListItem(item)).join(" ")} </ul>
        </li>`;
    }
    return `<li><a href="#${li.MenuName}" >${li.MenuName}</a></li>`;
}
```

and now you can create a sidebar dynamically :

```
var x = new SideBar(menus);
// add your own onclick as you like 
x.onclick = t=>{
    console.log(`clicked!`,t);
};
x.attach(document.querySelector("nav.collapse"));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks your code are very helpful, but may i ask you one more question please. How to insert the JSON to DB

Comment: e.g ( INSERT INTO Menus () VALUES (); )

Comment: Because the MenuList is Array, in DB the DataType has no Array. I know my login is wrong, but any explain can let me to understand this please.

Comment: @HanWhuiTeh I saw you add a tag of `MySQL` . Are you using MySQL ? As of MySQL 5.7 , you can insert json directly . See[ reference here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

Comment: INSERT INTO `book` (`title`, `tags`)
VALUES (
  'ECMAScript 2015: A SitePoint Anthology',
  '["JavaScript", "ES2015", "JSON"]'
);

Comment: izit somethings like this? And what is the MenuList DataType?

Comment: @HanWhuiTeh Nesting is permitted within JSON array elements and JSON object key values. So a JSON array will be ok .

Comment: So sry i dont understand, do you have an example can show to me please~

Comment: @HanWhuiTeh   create table : `create table mytable ( title VARCHAR(255), tags JSON );`  ; insert into : `insert into mytable values ('ES2015 : Good Parts','[{"MenuName":"m1","MenuList":[]},{"MenuName":"m2","MenuList":[]}]');`